# Why does this happen when I try to install react-toastify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, toast, react-toastify

[image]

How do I fix this. the toast functionality doesn't work.

I was trying to install `react-toastify`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75074943/8001538

Comment: Looks like you have some outdated dependencies in your project (those aren't dependencies of react-toastify). Anyway, they're just warnings, not errors, the library was installed. The reason why your toasts don't work is something else.

Comment: npm i react-toastify --legacy-peer-deps Use this command, I think it help you.